# closing a html form causing column text to move to next line in IE

Tags: asp.net, html, internet-explorer

I am using VPASP as a shopping cart and recently I noticed strange behavior in IE. I have products that are sold by the pack and by the case. So I made each item have 2 "Order" buttons. The way each product works is that in the ASP code, it sets up the start of the form and then runs a html template in which I make the order button and the quantity ordered space. I then have to issue the `</form>` command so I can start the form for the case. This code is working just fine and the problem isn't functionality... the problem is visual. The way it is set up, I have 4 columns under the picture of the item. The first column is the "features" of that item, the second column is for "options", the third column is for the Pack Order button, and the fourth column is for the Case Order button. The problem is, when I issue the `</form>` command after the Pack Order button, the fourth column is being kicked to the next line. If I remove the `</form>` command, the fourth column is positioned exactly where it should be, but then the cart no longer works.

Of course Firefox ignores this little bit of code and displays perfectly, but when I go to IE... fail. [You can see an example by visiting this link to a page of the site.](http://www.baitmasters.com/store/shopdisplayproducts.asp?id=31&cat=rigballyhoo) If you visit the site in Firefox it will be perfect, but also check in IE and you will see the visual problems I'm encountering. Is there some trick to getting IE to not push a column to the next line after issuing the `</form>` command?

Here is a sample of the code I'm using to make this work (shorted a bit with a little psudo code for ease of reading):

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="1" width="100%" align="center">
<tr>
<td class="al vt">
<form name="prodname" action="shopaddtocart.asp" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="productid" value="10" />
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td width="100%" align="left">
<strong>Product Title</strong>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
    <tr>
    <td width="100%" valign="top">
    <img src="product_image.jpg" border="0" alt="Image"><br />
        <div style="width: 100%; left: 0%; clear: both; float: left; overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
            <div style="right: 20%; float: left; width: 100%; position: relative;">
                <div style="right: 20%; float: left; width: 100%; position: relative;">
                    <div style="right: 30%; float: left; width: 100%; position: relative;">
                        <div class="column1">
                            Product Options
                        </div>
                        <div class="column2">
                            Product Features
                        </div>
                        <div class="column3">
                            <input class="txtfield" type="text" maxlength="4" size="3" value="1" name="quantity" />
                            <input class="submitbtn" type="submit" value=" Order " name="Order" />
                            </form> <!-- IF I REMOVE THIS THEN IE DISPLAYS CORRECTLY BUT CART STOPS WORKING -->
                        </div>
                        <div class="column4">
                            <form name="casename" action="shopaddtocart.asp" method="post">
                            <input type="hidden" name="productid" value="23">
                            <input class="txtfield" type="text" maxlength="4" size="3" value="1" name="quantity" />
                            <input class="submitbtn" type="submit" value=" Order " name="Order" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form></td></tr>
```

Comment: Your html and css display correctly in Document Mode: IE7 standards, but, as you've explained, are odd in IE8, IE9.  There is a LOT of css here and a ton of junk html that isn't needed to get this layout.  The order of some of the html is a little odd as well.  My guess is your trouble might be coming from the order you are closing your tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit more research.  It seems like the problem is stemming from the manner in which the forms have been nested.

See here:  http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/forms.html#the-form-element

> 4.10.3 The form element
>
> Content model:
>
> Flow content, but with no form element descendants.

If you paste your html above into jsfiddle and hit TidyUp you will see that a lot of your tags are not well formed.  See here:  http://jsfiddle.net/Bppj9/

If you could try something like this instead, it might help:

http://jsfiddle.net/methuselah/rCtGd/

The main part you should focus on would be cleaning up the wrapping code around your columns:

```
#content-1 {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    background: #bfb;
}
#content-2 {
    float: right;
    width: 80%;
}
#content-2-1 {
    float: left;
    width: 55%;
    background: #ddf;
}
```

Furthermore these resources can help you in understanding a bit in properly setting up more fluid columns:

- http://css-tricks.com/the-perfect-fluid-width-layout/
- http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/fluid-layout-code/

I tried to clean up your HTML so that the tags were closed in the proper order as well, but honestly, it's in a pretty rough spot and it would be worth re-working it a bit using the resources above.

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="1" width="100%" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td class="al vt">
            <form name="prodname" action="shopaddtocart.asp" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="productid" value="10" />
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                    <td width="100%" align="left">
                        <strong>Product Title</strong>
                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="100%" valign="top">
                                    <img src="product_image.jpg" border="0" alt="Image">
                                    <br />
                                    <div style="width: 100%; left: 0%; clear: both; float: left; overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
                                        <div style="right: 20%; float: left; width: 100%; position: relative;">
                                            <div style="right: 20%; float: left; width: 100%; position: relative;">
                                                <div style="right: 30%; float: left; width: 100%; position: relative;">
                                                    <div class="column1">
                                                        Product Options</div>
                                                    <div class="column2">
                                                        Product Features</div>
                                                    <div class="column3">
                                                        <input class="txtfield" type="text" maxlength="4" size="3" value="1" name="quantity" />
                                                        <input class="submitbtn" type="submit" value=" Order " name="Order" />
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </form>
            <div class="column4">
                <form name="casename" action="shopaddtocart.asp" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="productid" value="23">
                <input class="txtfield" type="text" maxlength="4" size="3" value="1" name="quantity" />
                <input class="submitbtn" type="submit" value=" Order " name="Order" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments and links. That jsfiddle was helpful. In truth I had put in the CSS columns because I though it was an issue with the html jumble that was there to begin with, but when it didn't fix the issue I just never looked back. Well today I did look back and using the html code only and that jsfiddle tidyup feature I was able to get it working like it used to in IE. Thanks!